# Angular 2: Programmatically to position inside div overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, primeng

I've customized a [PrimeNg TabView](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabview) and wrapped it inside a custom component in order to achieve this:

[image: My TabView Component]

As you can see the tabview content has `overflow-x: hidden` so it can look better, to allow users to navigate between tabs that are hidden I've add two buttons, one on each side of the tabview.

Now I am trying to develop those buttons click functionality and I dont know how I can achieve that.

This is how my component looks like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <a id="back" class="ripple" [style.backgroundColor]="ui.currentThemeBackground"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
 <p-tabView styleClass="tab-container" [style]="{'background-color':ui.currentThemeBackground}">
   <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let tab of store.linhaTempo | async; let i = index; "
  [id]="index" [header]="tab.titulo" [selected]="tab.selecionada"></p-tabPanel>
 </p-tabView>
 <a id="forward" class="ripple" [style.backgroundColor]="ui.currentThemeBackground"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a>
</div>


linha-tempo .wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
}

linha-tempo .tab-container {
  border: none !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  border-radius: 0px;
 }

linha-tempo #back, linha-tempo #forward {
  width: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  line-height: 33px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

linha-tempo #back {
  left: 0px;
}

linha-tempo #forward {
  right:0px;
}

linha-tempo #back i, linha-tempo #forward i {
  line-height: 2;
  color: white;
}

linha-tempo .ui-tabview-panel {
  display: none !important;
}

linha-tempo .ui-tabview-nav, linha-tempo .ui-tabview-nav > li.ui-state-active {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

linha-tempo .ui-tabview-nav {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

linha-tempo .ui-tabview-nav > li {
  border: none !important;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

linha-tempo .ui-tabview-nav > li.ui-state-active {
  color: white;
}

linha-tempo .ui-tabview-nav a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

linha-tempo .ui-tabview-nav > li.ui-state-active a {
  color: white !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  cursor: default !important;
}

body .ui-tabview .ui-tabview-nav > li.ui-state-hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: On your js, when the forward is clicked. You can hacked the positioning of tabview or move it using transform, margin, etc. Same on back. Can you show us your javascript code? So, we can see errors on your code. Thanks!!

Comment: @HermLuna Hello! Sorry but I havent implemented nothing yet, I have no clue of how to do that in a proper way.. actually I was looking for suggestions of how to do it hehe

Comment: The answer from Abhishek is good. All of the methods you need to use is on his/w3 demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried scrolling left and right for a div on click.

You can do the same for tabs as well.

Kindly look into the following link for detailed reference

http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAB7S70J7UZD

Please let me know in case of any query.